# why the subprocess.run with ssh closed parent process' stdin pipe

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, stdin

I have 2 python scripts:

```
# foo.py
import time
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo():
    subprocess.run(["ssh", "localhost", "sleep", "10"]) # i use ssh-key to login, no password needed

p = Process(target=foo)
p.start()
x = input("i1")
x = input("i2")
```

```
# bar.py
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "foo.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE) # bar.py is in the same folder with foo.py
while True:
    p.stdin.write(bytes(input("bar,")+"\n", "utf-8"))
    p.stdin.flush()
```

running `bar.py` would result in:

```bash
.....
    x = input("i2")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I wonder this line get a EOF from the stdin pipe (since i didn't send any EOF to it in `bar.py`)

i'd expect no EOF exception, and `foo.py` finished gracefully.

notes:
The scripts were simplified, to make the problem more clear. I'm actually creating some daemon program in `foo.py`, and use `bar.py` to input "enter" key like "SIG_TERM" for it to stop.

Comment: this seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you really trying to do? additionally `bar.py` is missing a closing parenthesis `)` on the first line of the loop so you may be seeing a SyntaxError from that .. finally, are you piping the output of `bar.py` to another process which isn't reading its `stdout`?

Comment: @ti7 I'm not piping the output of bar.py. By the way, I found the solution is setting "stdin=subprocess.PIPE" in foo.py, so the ssh line won't eat the parent's stdin.

Comment: excellent - you may Answer your own Question to gain reputation and improve the community!